# cannot create dynamic tables with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This Code is supposed to create a table and transform it into a canvas, so that when I click a cell it changes it color to the color picker *the input is taken from the text boxes and color picker and executed when submit is pressed*

I want to create a table with a certain height and width.
The Problem is that I don't know how to store the values of the input boxes
to create the table.
the second problem is I want to store the color from the color picker too to change the cells color to it when I click them.[Photo of the page running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmOzP.png).

Note: I am only allowed to solve this with JQuery.

```js
// Select color input
// Select size input

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
var Make=$('#pixel_canvas');
var td=$('td');

var rows=$('#input_width').val();
var cols=$('#input_height').val();
td.css("padding","700px");
function change() {
    $('td').click( function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
}

Make.append(makeGrid());

function makeGrid() {
    var table='';

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         table+='<tr>';
         for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
             table+='<td onclick="change()"></td>';
         }
         table+='</tr>';
    }
    return table;
};
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixel_canvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create HTML table dynamically, You need to add the number of rows in a loop. You need for that to form the string that will be added in your html.

- A common way to do that is to start your string with `"<table>"`. Then you will add to this string the number of rows (generally using a loop) and then you will add after the loop `"</table>"` to end your string.
- But in your example, the `table` tag exists already in your html, so it is not necessary to start or close our string with the `table` tag. We will append the string describing our rows directly to the selector `$(#pixel_canvas)`

Then if you want to create listeners on the `td` tag of your table, you can use delegation event. This way, you will add a single listener for the whole table. Basically, instead of `table+='<td onclick="change()"></td>';`, you can do this: `$('#pixel_canvas').on('click', 'td', function(e){})`

```js
let color;

//make the Grid of pixel art
function makeGrid() {
 const table = $('#pixel_canvas');
 table.find('tr').remove(); // will delete existing table if there is

 const size = {
 height: $('#input_height').val(),
 width: $('#input_width').val()
 }

 //Construct the table
 for (let i = 0; i < size.height; i++) {
  let row = '<tr>';
  let cell = '';
  for(let j = 0; j < size.width; j++){
   cell += '<td></td>';
  }
  row += cell;
  row += '</tr>';
  table.append(row);
 }

}

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
$('#sizePicker').on('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 makeGrid()
})

//change cell color
$('#pixel_canvas').on('click', 'td', function(e){
 if($(e.target).css('background-color') !== color){
  //if color cell different from the selected color with color picker
  color = $('#colorPicker').val();
  $(e.target).css('background-color', color);
  color = $(e.target).css('background-color'); // get the color value in RGB notation
 }else{
  $(e.target).css('background-color', 'inherit');
 }
})
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixel_canvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A big blob of code without an explanation is not very valuable...even if the code works

Comment: add some description to what he was doing wrong and what should be changed to achieve, this would be nice

Comment: I add explanations in the code, but I will edit my answer

Comment: yeah but it is not very good pattern to require form people to parse the code to have a overview

Comment: @edkeveked thank you so much you helped me a lot  :D <3

Comment: "Practice makes perfect", as long as you keep practicing, you will become a good js developer @AhmedSamy :)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, I updated the answer. I was just calling the makeGrid() function